# How to produce Cauchy noise when the image intensity range is [0,255]?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have written the following code to produce Cauchy noise for an image when the image intensity range is [0,1]:

```
refimg = im2double(((imread('parrot.png')))); % original image
img_height = size(refimg,1);
img_width = size(refimg,2);

r1 = random('Normal',0, 1,[img_height img_width]);
r2 = random('Normal',0, 1,[img_height img_width]);

n = 0.04; % the noise level
u0 = refimg + n.*(r1./r2);

figure(1); imshow(u0);
```

And this is the result that I obtained:

[image]

Now I want to change the intensity range of my reference image to [0,255] and produce the noisy image corrupted by the Cauchy noise. For this purpose, I changed the first line to

```
refimg = im2double(((imread('parrot.png')))).*255; % original image
```

and the last line to:

```
figure(1); imshow(u0,[]);
```

But this is the output:

[image]

I appreciate it if someone could please help me to find the problem with my code when the image intensity range is [0,255].

Comment: If you want to put your image in intensity range from zero to 255, it's not enough to multiply all the values with 255. Use the `rescale` function for this task : `refimg = rescale(im2double(imread('parrot.png')),0,255);`.
Then you should think about how to adjust the noise level, `r1` and `r2`..

Comment: @Till Many thanks for your comment. I rescaled the intensity range between 0 and 255. My matlab version did not have the rescale function so I did it as follows:`refimg1 = im2double(((imread('parrott.png')))); % original image
img_height = size(refimg1,1);
img_width = size(refimg1,2);
newMin = 0; newMax = 255;
oldMin = min(min(refimg1));
oldMax = max(max(refimg1));
refimg = (refimg1-oldMin).*((newMax-newMin)./(oldMax-oldMin)) + newMin;` But there was no change in the result.

Comment: Just multiplying by 255 is fine, no need to do anything else. But now your noise is 255 times smaller relative to the pixel values. So just multiply the noise by 255 as well. See also my comment on the answer below.

Comment: Oh, you might want to show the output image as `imshow(u0,[0,255])`, since that matches how you show the other noisy image. The Cauchy do distribution  will have very large and very small values, if you scale to those you’ll not be able to see the image.

Comment: Exactly, you are right. Many thanks for your comment. I checked my code using the directions in your comment and it works. Thank you so much. @Cris Luengo

Comment: @Cris Luengo  I really appreciate it if you could please help me to understand why psnr function for noisy image produced with my code returns a negative value. I have written the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872113/why-psnr-function-in-matlab-returns-a-negative-value-for-an-image-corrupted-with/69872929#69872929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the output the noise can be scaled by 255 and casted as a `uint8` after being added to the reference image `refimg` to match the reference image, `refimg`. This results in an image that seems to replicate the image you had when it was handled as a double ranging from 0 to 1.

[image: Adding Noise to Image]

```
refimg = 255.*im2double(imread('tire.tif'));
img_height = size(refimg,1);
img_width = size(refimg,2);

r1 = random('Normal',0, 1,[img_height img_width]);
r2 = random('Normal',0, 1,[img_height img_width]);

n = 0.04; %the noise level%

Noise = 255.*n.*(r1./r2);
%Casting the noise as uint8 type and multiplying by 255%
u0 = uint8(refimg + Noise);

figure(1); 
subplot(1,3,1); imshow(uint8(refimg));
subplot(1,3,2); imshow(uint8(Noise));
subplot(1,3,3); imshow(u0);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer. I really appreciate it. I only have faced a question and I would be so grateful if you could please help me. When I run the code, the noisy parrot image contains Cauchy noise but no black particles are observed in the noisy image but as far as I know the Cauchy noise also consists of black particles. @MichaelTr7

Comment: Amazing catch I didn't even notice the missing black pixels. I've edited the question to apply the noise before casting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very helpful answer to my question. Yes, Now the noisy parrot test image contains black particles too. Many thanks. I really appreciate it. @MichaelTr7

Comment: I would be so grateful it if you could please guide me why psnr function for noisy image produced with my code returns a negative value. I have written the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872113/why-psnr-function-in-matlab-returns-a-negative-value-for-an-image-corrupted-with/69872929#69872929

Comment: @eli Looks like a fellow colleague has already clarified everything. Let me know if it’s still unclear.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with the psnr value of the noisy image is solved but when I compute the psnr value of the denoised image, I receive 17 which is not correct because the denoised image that my implementation of the paper produces is exactly the same as the paper and its psnr value must be around 28. I really appreciate it if you could please help me with this problem. I have written this problem in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880822/how-to-compute-the-psnr-value-for-a-denoised-image-corrupted-with-cauchy-noise @MichaelTr7

Comment: @eli I’m not too sure about this question to be truthfully honest. Seems pretty involved. Best of luck!