# Why psnr function in matlab returns a negative value for an image corrupted with Cauchy noise?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have written the following matlab code for producing a noisy image corrupted by Cauchy noise but when I compute the psnr value of the noisy image using psnr function in matlab, it returns a negetive value while according to the paper that I have implemented its results, the psnr value for the cameraman test image of size 256 by 256 and 0.02 of Cauchy noise must be around 19. I appreciate it if someone could please help me to solve this problem.

```
refimg = im2double(imread('cameraman.png')); % original image
img_height = size(refimg,1);
img_width = size(refimg,2);
refimg = refimg(1:img_height,1:img_width);

rng(0);
r1 = random('Normal',0, 1,[img_height img_width]);
r2 = random('Normal',0, 1,[img_height img_width]);

n = 0.02; % the noise level
u0 = refimg + n.*(r1./r2);

figure(1); imshow(u0);

PSNR_noisy = psnr(refimg,u0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it is Cauchy noise. 
@Luis Mendo

Comment: Thanks for your help but because I have implemented the results of a paper, I am sure that the psnr function must not return a negative value  in this case but I can not find the reason why my code returns a negative one.
@Luis Mendo

Comment: It can be negative because it is in decibels, as explained in my answer. The `psnr` function produces the output that way. If you want the result in linear units use `10^(PSNR_noisy/10)`

Comment: Many thanks but using 10^(PSNR_noisy/10), I get the value 0.0018 for psnr which still is not true because according to the paper the psnr value of cameraman image corrupted by cauchy noise 0.02 must be around 19. For this reason I am sure that there is something wrong with the code but I can not find it. @Luis Mendo

Comment: Not sure if I can be of more help, but what does “0.02 of Cauchy noise” mean exactly? How is that 0.02 interpreted?

Comment: Thank you for your time and your help. n=0.02 is the Cauchy noise level. @Luis Mendo

Comment: My point is: how do you define “level” for a distribution that does not have variance or even mean?

Comment: Since the ratio of two standard normal variables gives a standard Cauchy random variable, I generate the noisy image u0 by: u0 = refimg + n.*(r1./r2). Here n gives the noise level and r1 and r2 follow the Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1. @Luis Mendo

Comment: The Cauchy distribution has infinite variance, so the noise power is infinity. Does it really make sense to apply `psnr` here? (I’m not an expert in image processing)

Comment: Yes, we can apply psnr function but I am not sure about the correctness of my code. @Luis Mendo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Luis Mendo nicely stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69872929/7328782), you cannot compute the power of noise taken from a Cauchy distribution. This is because the distribution doesn't have a mean or a variance. You can get infinitely large (or small) values from this distribution. Because of this lack of mean and variance, it doesn't make sense as a noise model for an image. However, if we were to clamp the values of the image after applying noise, then we would be able to sensibly compute statistics.

This is OP's code, slightly simplified and amended to clamp the image values to the [0,1] range after adding the noise:

```matlab
refimg = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')); % original image
sz = size(refimg);
rng(0);
r1 = randn(sz); % (using randn because I don't have the statistics toolbox)
r2 = randn(sz);
n = 0.02; % the noise level
u0 = refimg + n.*(r1./r2);
u0 = min(u0,1); % clamp large values to 1
u0 = max(u0,0); % clamp small values to 0
PSNR_noisy = psnr(u0,refimg)
```

The output now is 19.1419.

---

Note that the function `psnr` expects the reference image to be the second input, even though the switch doesn't affect the output in this case.

---

Please read my opinion here on using PSNR: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/490/

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thank you so much for your helpful answer. Now the psnr value of noisy image is 19 but when I compute the psnr value of the denoised image, I receive 17 which is not correct because the denoised image that my implementation of the paper produces is exactly the same as the paper and its psnr value must be around 28. I would be so grateful if you could please help me to solve this too if you have time. I have written this problem in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880822/how-to-compute-the-psnr-value-for-a-denoised-image-corrupted-with-cauchy-noise

Answer (score 5):

The [`psnr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/psnr.html) function outputs the signal-to-noise ratio in [decibels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) (that is, logarithtmic units). This is stated [in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/psnr.html#bt5uhgi-4) (but I think it should be indicated more clearly, perhaps in the description section). Also, a quick look at `psnr`'s code confirms that the outputs are given in decibels:

> `peaksnr = 10*log10(peakval.^2/err);`
>
> `snr = 10*log10(mean(ref(:).^2)/err);`

Therefore the result can be negative, meaning there is more noise power than signal power.

Note, however, that the concept of noise power cannot be applied to a Cauchy distribution. So I’m not sure it makes sense to use `psnr` in this case.