# How to compute the psnr value for a denoised image corrupted with Cauchy noise?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The following is my implementation of a paper for cauchy noise removal.
The psnr value of the noisy image is 19 as the paper but when I compute the psnr value for the restored image un, it returns 17 which is even smaller than the psnr value of the noisy image. I guess there is something wrong in psnr computation with my code.

```
%%
clear memory;
clear all
close all
clc;

%% Initialization

refimg = im2double(imread('cameraman256.png')); % original image
img_height = size(refimg,1);
img_width = size(refimg,2);
refimg = refimg(1:img_height,1:img_width);

padNum = 5;
refimg = padarray(refimg,[padNum,padNum],'symmetric');
[mm,nn]=size(refimg);
img_height = size(refimg,1);
img_width = size(refimg,2);

%% Producing the degraded image

A = 1;  % A =1 for image denoising

sz = size(refimg);
rng(0);
r1 = randn(sz); % (using randn because I don't have the statistics toolbox)
r2 = randn(sz);
n = 0.02; % the noise level
u0 = refimg + n.*(r1./r2);
u0 = min(u0,1); % clamp large values to 1
u0 = max(u0,0); % clamp small values to 0

figure(1); imshow(u0(padNum+1:mm-padNum,padNum+1:nn-padNum),'border','tight');

%% Initial values for the primal-dual algorithm

tol = 1e-3;
nIter = 1e3;
options.order = 1; options.bound = 'sym';
un = u0;
wn = u0;
bun = un;
bwn = wn;
pxn = zeros(ny,nx);
pyn = zeros(ny,nx);
q = zeros(ny,nx);
[gxn,gyn] = grad(u0,options);
bgxn = gxn;
bgyn = gyn;

gamma = sqrt(2)/10;
lambda = 0.7;
mu = 6.25; 

tau = 0.3;
sigma = 0.3;

%% Primal-dual Algorithm

for j = 1:nIter 

     %%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem p
     [ux,uy]=grad(bun,options);
     pxn = pxn+sigma*(bgxn-ux);
     pyn = pyn+sigma*(bgyn-uy);
     
     %%%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem q
     AUk = Au(bun);
     q = q+sigma*(bwn-AUk);

     %%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem g
     goldxn = gxn;
     goldyn = gyn;
     txn = gxn-tau*pxn;
     tyn = gyn-tau*pyn;
     sn = max(1e-6,sqrt(txn.^2+tyn.^2));
     gxn = txn./sn.*max(0,sn-tau);
     gyn = tyn./sn.*max(0,sn-tau);
     
    %%%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem wn
    u_medfilter = medfilt2(u0);
    wold = wn;
    
    a = mu.*lambda.*tau+1;
    b = -(mu.*lambda.*tau.*(2.*u0+u_medfilter)-tau.*q+2.*u0+wold);
    c = tau.*lambda+mu.*lambda.*tau.*(gamma.^2+u0.^2+2.*u_medfilter.*u0)-2.*tau.*q.*u0+...
         gamma.^2+u0.^2+2.*wold.*u0;
    d = -tau.*lambda.*u0-mu.*lambda.*tau.*u_medfilter.*(gamma.^2+u0.^2)+tau.*q.*(gamma.^2+u0.^2)...
        -wold.*(gamma.^2+u0.^2);
    
    qval = (3.*a.*c-(b.^2))./(9.*(a.^2));
    rval = (9.*a.*b.*c-27.*(a.^2).*d-2.*(b.^3))./(54.*(a.^3));
    deltaval = qval.^3+rval.^2;
    
    wn = nthroot(rval+real(sqrt(deltaval)),3)+nthroot(rval-real(sqrt(deltaval)),3)-((b)./(3.*a));
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem un
     uold = un;
     Asqk = Atu(q);
     un = un+tau*(Asqk-div(pxn,pyn,options)); % the restored image
      
%      un = min(1,max(0.01,un));
     
     if (norm(un-uold, 'fro')/norm(uold,'fro')<tol)  
           break;
     end 
     
     bun = 2*un-uold;
     bwn = 2*wn-wold;
     bgxn = 2*gxn-goldxn;
     bgyn = 2*gyn-goldyn;
     
%      PSNR_restoredimage = psnr(refimg(padNum+1:mm-padNum,padNum+1:nn-b 
      padNum),un(padNum+1:mm-padNum,padNum+1:nn-padNum))

end

%% Dispaly results

New_un = un;

refimg = refimg(padNum+1:mm-padNum,padNum+1:nn-padNum);
u0 = u0(padNum+1:mm-padNum,padNum+1:nn-padNum);
u_medfilter = u_medfilter(padNum+1:mm-padNum,padNum+1:nn-padNum); 
New_un = New_un(padNum+1:mm-padNum,padNum+1:nn-padNum);   

PSNR_noisy = psnr(refimg,u0)
PSNR_med = psnr(refimg,u_medfilter)
PSNR_restoredimage = psnr(New_un,refimg)

figure(2); imshow([refimg,u_medfilter,New_un],'border','tight'); 

%%
```

Comment: "exactly the same as the paper": how do you know ? If the PSNR of the first image is correct, I would question the implementation of the denoising.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Since I receive a denoised image similar to the paper, I know that there must be something wrong in my code and I guess that my psnr computation is not correct.

Comment: "similar" is not "exactly the same". Cheers.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Thank you. I have edited my question.

Comment: I don’t know if it matters, but as I said earlier, the reference image should be the second input to `psnr`, not the first one. You should also make sure your images don’t have values outside the expected [0,1] range, otherwise the PSNR calculation fails.

Comment: Does the median filter increase the PSNR?

Comment: @ Cris Luengo, thank you so much for your comment. I have checked that the reference image should be the second input to psnr and in this case the result was the same. Yes, the median filter increases the psnr and the denoised image does not have values outside [0,1]. Its min is 0.0232 and its max is 0.9635.

Comment: I can't run your code, it has too many underlined functions in it. I figured out how to replace `padPSF` with `padarray`, but then there's `grad` and who knows what else, so this is too much work for me to figure out. PSNR is based on the mean square error between the two images. Look at the difference between the restored and the reference image (use `imshow(refimg-un,[])` to scale the output so you see also the negative values), that might give you a hint as to what is going on. Note also that `psnr(refimg,refimg+0.1)` is already 20, so look at the actual values in that difference.

Comment: Note that `clear memory` clears a variable called `memory` from the workspace, "memory" is not any specific option to `clear`. And `clear all` is usually not needed. `clear` by itself clears all variables from memory. `clear all` also clears all loaded functions, which means your code will run slower as those functions must be loaded again. Just do `clear` at the top of your code.

Comment: @Cris Luengo  Thank you so much for your valuable comments and time. I solved the problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in psnr computation. The problem with my code in this question was that I was considering the denoising case but I had forgotten to omit the blur kernel in primal-dual algorithm. Also, the initial parameters corresponding to the deblurring case must be zero. The following is the corrected code. Now the psnr value is 28 similar to the paper.

```
%%
clear;

%% Initialization

refimg = im2double(imread('cameraman256.png')); % original image
img_height = size(refimg,1);
img_width = size(refimg,2);
refimg = refimg(1:img_height,1:img_width);

%% Producing the noisy image

sz = size(refimg);
rng(0);
r1 = randn(sz); % (using randn because I don't have the statistics toolbox)
r2 = randn(sz);
n = 0.02; % the noise level
u0 = refimg + n.*(r1./r2);
u0 = min(u0,1); % clamp large values to 1
u0 = max(u0,0); % clamp small values to 0

figure(1); imshow(u0,'border','tight');

%% Initial values for the primal-dual algorithm

init = u0;
[ny,nx] = size(init);
tol = 1e-3;
nIter = 1e3;
options.order = 1; options.bound = 'sym';
un = u0;
wn = zeros(ny,nx);
bun = un;
bwn = zeros(ny,nx);
pxn = zeros(ny,nx);
pyn = zeros(ny,nx);
q = zeros(ny,nx);
[gxn,gyn] = grad(u0,options);
bgxn = gxn;
bgyn = gyn;

gamma = sqrt(2)/10;
lambda = 0.7;
mu = 6.25; 

tau = 0.3;
sigma = 0.3;

%% Primal-dual Algorithm

for j = 1:nIter 

      %%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem p
      [ux,uy]=grad(bun,options);
      pxn = pxn+sigma*(bgxn-ux);
      pyn = pyn+sigma*(bgyn-uy);
      
      %%%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem q
      AUk = bun;
      q = q+sigma*(bwn-AUk);

      %%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem g
      goldxn = gxn;
      goldyn = gyn;
      txn = gxn-tau*pxn;
      tyn = gyn-tau*pyn;
      sn = max(1e-6,sqrt(txn.^2+tyn.^2));
      gxn = txn./sn.*max(0,sn-tau);
      gyn = tyn./sn.*max(0,sn-tau);
      
     %%%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem wn
     u_medfilter = medfilt2(u0);
     wold = wn;
     
     a = mu.*lambda.*tau+1;
     b = -(mu.*lambda.*tau.*(2.*u0+u_medfilter)-tau.*q+2.*u0+wold);
     c = tau.*lambda+mu.*lambda.*tau.*(gamma.^2+u0.^2+2.*u_medfilter.*u0)-2.*tau.*q.*u0+...
          gamma.^2+u0.^2+2.*wold.*u0;
     d = -tau.*lambda.*u0-mu.*lambda.*tau.*u_medfilter.*(gamma.^2+u0.^2)+tau.*q.*(gamma.^2+u0.^2)...
         -wold.*(gamma.^2+u0.^2);
     
     qval = (3.*a.*c-(b.^2))./(9.*(a.^2));
     rval = (9.*a.*b.*c-27.*(a.^2).*d-2.*(b.^3))./(54.*(a.^3));
     deltaval = qval.^3+rval.^2;
     
     wn = nthroot(rval+real(sqrt(deltaval)),3)+nthroot(rval-real(sqrt(deltaval)),3)-((b)./(3.*a));
     
     %%%%%%%%%%%solve the subproblem un
      uold = un;
      Asqk = q;
      un = un+tau*(Asqk-div(pxn,pyn,options)); % the restored image
 
      
      if (norm(un-uold, 'fro')/norm(uold,'fro')<tol)  
            break;
      end 
      
      bun = 2*un-uold;
      bwn = 2*wn-wold;
      bgxn = 2*gxn-goldxn;
      bgyn = 2*gyn-goldyn;
       
end

%% Dispaly results

PSNR_noisy = psnr(u0,refimg)
PSNR_med = psnr(u_medfilter,refimg)
PSNR_restoredimage = psnr(un,refimg)

figure(2); imshow([refimg,u_medfilter,un],'border','tight'); 

%%
```